# Internationalization - Loading many locales and the supplemental data

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

The example only shows loading of 1 locale which is bg.
How are we able to load all the locale so that we can change the locale dynamically. Thanks in advance!

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ucx0SlcmBfN9TRjrS5Ad?p=preview `Plunker`

Answer (score 0):

**[Short answer]**

You can't change the locale of the Angular application dynamically, without recreating the module/component.

**[Long version]**

The locale of the Angular component is determined by the [`LOCALE_ID`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/LOCALE_ID-let.html), which is injected through the Angular DI system. Considering the fact the Angular uses *constructor based dependency injection*, the component needs to be recreated in order to receive new `LOCALE_ID` value.

That being said, the only feasible solution to have components/modules with different locales is to wrap them with high order component that will provide different LOCALE_ID:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bg',
  providers: [{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useValue: 'bg-BG'
  }, { 
    provide: IntlService,
    useFactory: (localeId: string) => new CldrIntlService(localeId),
    deps: [LOCALE_ID]
  }],
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class BGComponent {
}
```

Here is runnable demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gmAWVLD1Yzn353QA1eDj?p=preview

*Please note, that the plunker demonstrates how to place components with different locale on one page. As I mentioned, fully dynamic change of the locale is not possible (excluding the all possible hacks, of course). If there is a good solution out there using `LOCALE_ID`, I'd be more than happy to see it.*